# Laravel 7 Instagram feed with basic display API

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

I need to insert instagram feed in my Laravel 7 based website.

Till this time i used instafeedjs, but soon that won't work.

I allready created FB app and test user, but i am not so strong in programming to create functions with tokens and getting information.

Authentication in my website with IG isn't necessary. I looked across web to find some tutorials but couldn't.

I would like to find some toturial for Laravel 7 how to do that proper way or any other information that helps me achieve my task. Im stright forward to learn not only copy paste code, but if you have code samples will be interested to use it and inspect them for learning.

Comment: So what have your tried so far? We can see you've searched for tutorials but couldnt find one. Have you tried anything yourself? After one quick search i've found this bundle made by Dymantic. https://github.com/Dymantic/laravel-instagram-feed

Comment: @Collin I did all the steps till "Getting Authorize" and dont have an idea how to manage this further...

Comment: The Getting Authorize section explains the authorization of the user. This is not a well-known bundle for me but you might be able to skip this step if you do not want authorizaiton.

Comment: @Collin i guess auth is necessery for getting token  and after that getting feed